# Is it allowed to not EAT at suhur and iftar?

Tags: halal-haram, sawm, ramadan, food

I wanted to do a water fast for the whole month of Ramadan but I'm not sure if it is allowed to not eat at all. So I would break my fast with water instead of food.

Answer (score 1):

For breaking the fast you only need to eat or drink something or have a (halal) physical relation. So yes it would be acceptable and technically correct (fiqh perspective) to break fast by only drinking water. But you won't be following the sunnah by eating at least some dates etc. and I doubt that it would be good for your health to do this a longer time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So If I only eat dates in Ramadan I would follow the sunnah?

Comment: There are many sunnan one could follow during Ramadan I just quoted one of them which more exactly is to break fast with an odd amount of dates. It is also sunnah to break fast as early as possible and start it as late as possible, by consuming food/beverage as soon as the sun goes down and by eating/drinking until the adhan of fajr starts.